# How to find the current source Is and the voltage V1 of this circuit schematic?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

[image: My problem is here]

I have Vs= 1.5V, R1=1 Ohm, R2 =6 Ohms, I got the equivalent resistance to be 7 Ohms. Then I set equal Req to Vs for 7I=1.5 and got my current source to be 0.214A. Since it is only Vs and Req in the circuit now, I did -Vs+V1=0 which got me 1.5V for V1. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: I realized the last resistor value was cut off. It is 2R2 again. Here is a picture of the full circuit to make it more clear. [image: Full circuit]

Comment: `?` Resistance value on extreme right arm of schematic missing

Comment: My bad! It is 2R2 again. Didn't realize I cut it off

Comment: $V_1$ calculation should involve *only* the $R_1$ resistor, not the equivalent resistance.

Comment: what about the voltage divider rule? V1= -1.5(1/(1+12)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin systematically by calculating equivalent resistance of the circuit. So you will have a simplified circuit that consists of a voltage source and a resistor equal to the equivalent resistance of the circuit. By applying Ohm's law: Vs = Req x Is you obtain Is. Since R1 has the current Is flowing through it V1 = R1 x Is.

Req should be equal to 7 Ohm

Comment: Ahhh I see what I did wrong. Forgot about Ohm's law applying to finding V1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: V1 is taking up 1/7 of the total voltage. This comes from Voltage division rule: V1 = 1.5 * 1/(1+6). Another way to quickly solve by inspection is using Ohm's law. Since you know the resistance and current going through the resistor, you can find V1.